# Chrome in selenium - memory leaks

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, memory-leaks

I've got big problem with selenium and chrome (controlled by chromedriver). It looks like there is memory leak. When I repeadly run test on site, after few hours of work, memory consumption of chrome increase from 100Mb to 2GB. Does someone has similar problem and is it possible to solve it?

I think the problem is not in my program becouse this has constant memory size. The problem is only with chrome (or chromedriver do something badly)

Comment: I take the approach of restarting webdriver after each test.

Comment: So couple of things, a) Have you raised a bug with Chrome *and* ChromeDriver teams? We aren't those teams. They'll be best placed to tell you where the problem likely lies, b) Does it happen manually? I.e do a few things on the site, again and again and again, over the course of a few hours, does the same thing happen? c) Run the tests against a different browser, same thing? d) Run the tests against a different site - not easy, but mock up a similar thing in Chrome, does it happen there too? e) Is this a public facing site we can all go to? **Lots** of missing information.

Comment: 1 of my best practices is killing chrome.exe and chromedriver.exe before running any tests

Comment: same issue with firefox. unfortunately restarting webdriver is not a solution in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry about after nine years this issue still exists and found no reliable solutions or even suggestions.

I happend to solve this issue on some specific conditions, I don't promise this will work, but at least this method deserved your try.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)
# you actions here
driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

So, this solution is simple, just close the driver before quiting it. I don't know why this work, it seems that the driver.close() and driver.quit() have different procedure to exit the selenium, only use them both can you completely exit the selenium even when you met with issues. If anyone can tell me how it works, I will be really grateful, since Chatgpt and New bing just tell me driver.quit() can handle everything and there is no need to close the selenium first (obviously it was wrong).

I would list my situation so that you may get something from it.

1, I use multiple seleniums to crawl on website and I need to start and quit the selenium to get new ip.

2, My memory leak issue may happen when the selenium is out of control or fail to load the extensions (I have four extensions to load for proxy and other stuffs)